# Clipboard API Read/Write/Paste on a Non-SSL Site

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, clipboard, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an extension [bbCode for Web Extensions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bbcodewebex/), that automates adding tags to text for things like BBSes, blogs, etc.

I wanted to add symbols, which would prove useful for rich text editor boxes, but my current technique only works on plain text boxes and imput fields.  (It's ugly but irrelevant to the current discussion)

I've been running some test code using the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard), which is far more elegant than what I have been doing, and it works on the aforementioned rich text editor boxes, including those in iframes, but **ONLY** on SSL (https://) sites, not on insecure (http://) sites. (http:// sites are important because I know of a number of bulletin boards that do not use SSL because of cost, including the one that I admin)

Obviously, I can determine the connection and use different methods based on that, but I am trying to avoid that solution.

Below is the code that I am using, basically, it logs the current clipboard (clipboard read function not included here), copies the current selection to the clipboard, logs that, writes a string to the clipboard ("blblblblblbl"), and then pastes it.

It appears from the console log, that it is the `navigator.clipboard.writeText('blblblblblblblblblblblblblbl');`  which is not executing on insecure pages.

*On edit, it's just the clipboard.writeText that is not executing.*

Here is the code:

```
console.log("Current contents of clipboard",(await readFromClipboard()));
document.execCommand('copy'); //copy to clipboard
let copsel = await readFromClipboard();
console.log("selection copied to clipboard", await copsel);
await navigator.clipboard.writeText('blblblblblblblblblblblblblbl');
let afterBl = await readFromClipboard();
console.log("afterBl",afterBl);
document.execCommand('paste');
```

I have a page for this that I can load as either http or https as a test, [https://www.panix.com/~msaroff/cntedt.html](https://www.panix.com/%7Emsaroff/cntedt.html).

For an https page, the console log is:

```
Current contents of clipboard em ips
selection copied to clipboard Lorem ipsum 
afterBl blblblblblblblblblblblblblbl
```

And the stiring replaces the selected page.

For an HTTP page, the console log is:

```
Current contents of clipboard http://www.panix.com/~msaroff/cntedt.html
selection copied to clipboard Lorem ipsum
TypeError: navigator.clipboard is undefined
```

And no change is made to the page, and the clipboard contents do not become "blblblblbl", meaning that `navigator.clipboard.writeText`is not firing.

So is there a **JAVASCRIPT** (not jQuery, etc) solution to make this work?

Comment: fyi, it is HTTPS (HTTP using TLS), not SSH. Also jQuery **is JavaScript**, it is nothing special, in the event jQuery or any library does this, then you can do the same.

Comment: "because of cost", Google and other browsers disagree, certificates are available for free and TLS encryption has very very little cost on a relatively modern CPU. While I don't know the exact status of the different means of clipboard interaction, they are taking steps against unsecured sites, especially anything with a "login" as it exposes passwords, emails, etc.

Comment: Our host charges for ssh, so there is a cost, and migrating would have a non-trivial time cost for me.

Comment: As to jQuery being JavaScript, yes, it is, but implementing it involves differences in syntax which I find less intuitive, as well as the requirement to include the library, which further increases the size of the extension.